# VS Code extension: open file and show custom content without changing content

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'd like to implement a sistem in a **VS Code lsp extension**, which takes the content of a XML file and shows only the content between trigger tags without changing the real content of the file.

Example:

In vs code open pippo.xml file:

```
<trigger>
hello how are you?
</trigger>

<trigger>
This is a test.
</trigger>
```

I'd like to show only:

```
hello how are you?

This is a test.
```

But it falls in an **exception**:

> rejected promise not handled within 1 second: Error: cannot open uni://c:\users\baptiss\desktop\test\pippo.uni. Detail: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
> extensionHostProcess.js:105

> stack trace: Error: cannot open uni://c:\users\baptiss\desktop\test\pippo.uni. Detail: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
> at e.$g0.$tryOpenDocument (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/BaptisS/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code%20Insiders/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:2306:36550)

This is my provider:

```
class MyContentProvider implements vscode.TextDocumentContentProvider {
    private _onDidChange = new vscode.EventEmitter<vscode.Uri>();

    public provideTextDocumentContent(uri: vscode.Uri): string {
        const filePath = uri.fsPath;
        const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf-8');

        const regex = /<trigger>(.*?)<\/trigger>/s;
        const match = regex.exec(fileContent);
        const content = match ? match[1] : '';

        return content;
    }

    get onDidChange(): vscode.Event<vscode.Uri> {
        return this._onDidChange.event;
    }

    public update(uri: vscode.Uri) {
        this._onDidChange.fire(uri);
    }
}
```

```
// Registra il provider di contenuto personalizzato per lo schema di URI "mycontent"
const myContentProvider = new MyContentProvider();
vscode.workspace.registerTextDocumentContentProvider('uni', myContentProvider);
```

And this where i'm trying to open the file

```
// Crea un URI personalizzato per il documento
vscode.workspace.onDidOpenTextDocument(document => {
    if (path.extname(document.uri.fsPath) === '.xml') {
        const uri = vscode.Uri.parse(`uni://${document.uri.fsPath.replace('xml', 'uni')}`);
        vscode.workspace.openTextDocument(uri).then(document => {
            vscode.window.showTextDocument(document);
        });
    }
});
```